# Cannot do passwordless SSH from Mac to Ubuntu VM

Tags: ubuntu, mac, ssh, virtual-machine, rsa

I am trying to setup password less login from my Mac OS X to to Ubuntu VM created by Virtual-box. I am using NAT->port forwarding option in VM and have host port as 3022. When I do

> ssh -p 3022 ubuntu@127.0.0.1

from my local and I can able to login to ubuntu with password, and this works vice versa.

Now I have created public/private key file in my Mac and copied the pub key to VM (`ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys`)

So now when I do:

```
ssh -p 3022 ubuntu@127.0.0.1
```

and it's asking for the password again.

I verified the key from `id_rsa.pub` vs VM `authorized_keys` and key is same in both places

Can someone tell me if I am making any mistake in my steps?

Comment: Did you put the private key on your computer? `ssh -p 3022 -i /path/to/private_key ubuntu@127.0.0.1`

Comment: add a `-vv` to your ssh command, this should give you a lot of verbose output, that will help you troubleshoot.  Also look at your /var/log/auth.log on the Ubuntu server.

Comment: You may try to install `ssh-copy-id`, so it'll copy and configure RSA key for you.

Comment: yes @ecube I tried it now I am getting Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: @Zoredache thanks it helps to narrow down the issue, it says invalid user. Let me delete all the existing pub&private file and create a fresh set.

Comment: @Moogly make sure that your target has your public key in the connecting user's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

Comment: what errors you see in the server log?

Comment: @Jakuje Mar 10 09:57:49 ubuntu sshd[2082]: Invalid user ubuntu from 10.0.2.2
Mar 10 09:57:49 ubuntu sshd[2082]: input_userauth_request: invalid user ubuntu [preauth]
Mar 10 09:57:49 ubuntu sshd[2082]: Connection closed by 10.0.2.2 [preauth]

Comment: Reading that once again, I believe you will find out you don't have user `ubuntu` on your server so either create such a user or log in as some existing user.

Comment: it worked well by adding privatekey file and adding existing user "ssh -p 3022 -i /Users/sysuser/.ssh/wppvm wppuser@127.0.0.1" thanks